# Why did not generate PDF report after Publish

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am generating different type report about employee on my website. after publishing its could not generate clearly. if any case it not generate result a message will generate it have no value as result. it did not get after publishing. on local server its working fine. i give my code below. i don't know why this not working fine. how will set a path for all accessing (Client) machine.

my code is here.

```
BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false); //base font
Font font = new Font(bfTimes, 8, Font.BOLD); //Header File
Font font1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 7); //DateBase value
Font font2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 7); //sub headings
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(570f, 600f));
// string path = Server.MapPath("~/Computer/F/reports/");
//PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"F:\\reports\\" + "Employeebloodreportsectionwise.pdf", FileMode.Create));
//PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
doc.Open();
PdfPCell cell = null;
Phrase phrase = null;

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
//table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f ,40f});//column width
table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] {
  40f, 100f, 120f, 100f, 100f, 70f, 100f, 75f
}); //column width

PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(2);
table2.TotalWidth = 520f;
table2.LockedWidth = true;
table2.HorizontalAlignment = 0;

table.TotalWidth = 520f; //table size
//fix the absolute width of the table
table.LockedWidth = true;
//relative col widths in proportions - 1/3 and 2/3
//table.SetWidths(widths);
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
//leave a gap before and after the table
table.SpacingBefore = 10f; //both are used to mention the space from heading
table.SpacingAfter = 20f;
string imageURL = Server.MapPath(".") + "/companylogo.png";
iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);
//Resize image depend upon your need
jpg.ScaleToFit(110f, 100f);
//Give space before image
jpg.SpacingBefore = 10f;
//Give some space after the image
jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;
jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
doc.Add(jpg);

qry = "select CompanyName,Phone1,Address1,State,District from Company";
dr = conn1.query(qry);
if (dr.Read()) {
  string company1 = dr[0].ToString();

  Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 9, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED);
  Paragraph p = (new Paragraph("" + company1 + "", times));
  p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
  doc.Add(p);
  string Address = dr[2].ToString();
  string dist = dr[4].ToString();
  string state1 = dr[3].ToString();
  Font times1 = new Font(bfTimes, 7);
  Paragraph p1 = (new Paragraph("Address:" + Address + "," + state1 + "," + dist + "", times1));
  p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
  doc.Add(p1);

  string phone = dr[1].ToString();
  //Font times1 = new Font(bfTimes, 10);
  Paragraph p7 = (new Paragraph("PH:" + phone + "", times1));
  p7.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
  doc.Add(p7);



  Font times2 = new Font(bfTimes, 8, Font.BOLD);
  Paragraph p2 = (new Paragraph(" Department Wise Gender  Report", times2));
  p2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
  doc.Add(p2);

  Paragraph p8 = (new Paragraph("Department:" + dddept.SelectedItem.Text + "", times1));
  p8.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
  doc.Add(p8);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sl.no", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Emp Code", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  //cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Department", font));
  //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  //table.AddCell(cell);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Section", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Designation", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Dob", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Place", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Mobile", font));
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  table.AddCell(cell);

  //cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Blood Group", font));
  //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
  //table.AddCell(cell);
  //qry = "select EmpCode from EmpDetails where StatusID=1";
  //dt2 = conn1.gettable(qry);
  //if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
  //{
  //    foreach(DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
  //    {
  //    string code = Convert.ToString(row2["EmpCode"]);
  qry = "select EmpCode,Name,DeptName,sectname,Desgname,convert(varchar(15),Dob,103)As Dob,Sex,Place,Mobile,Blood  from View_EmpDetails where Blood='" + ddblood.SelectedItem.Text + "' and Deptid='" + dddept.SelectedItem.Value + "' And StatusID='1'";
  dt = conn1.gettable(qry); {
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
      int slno = 1;
      foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + slno + "", font2));
        table.AddCell(cell);

        EmpCode = Convert.ToString(row["EmpCode"]);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + EmpCode + "", font2));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        name = Convert.ToString(row["Name"]);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + name + "", font2));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //dept = Convert.ToString(row["DeptName"]);
        //cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + dept + "", font2));
        //cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        //table.AddCell(cell);

        sect = Convert.ToString(row["sectname"]);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + sect + "", font2));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        string desig = Convert.ToString(row["Desgname"]);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + desig + "", font2));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        string dob = Convert.ToString(row["Dob"]);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + dob + "", font2));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        string place = Convert.ToString(row["Place"]);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + place + "", font2));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        string mobile = Convert.ToString(row["Mobile"]);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + mobile + "", font2));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        slno++;
      }
      table2.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
      table2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
      table2.AddCell(new Phrase("Department: " + dddept.SelectedItem.Text + "", times2));
      table2.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
      table2.AddCell(new Phrase("Blood Group: " + ddblood.SelectedItem.Text + "", times2));
      doc.Add(table2);
      doc.Add(table);
      DateTime today = System.DateTime.Today;
      string today2 = today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
      Paragraph p6 = (new Paragraph("Genrated Date:" + today2 + "", times2));
      p6.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
      doc.Add(p6);
      //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"F:\\reports\\" + "Employeebloodreportsectionwise.pdf");
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FilePath);
      refresh();
    } else {
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No employees in selected blood group in this department  ..!!');", true);
      doc.Close();
    }
    doc.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=BloodGroupReport.pdf");
    Response.Write(doc);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

  }
```

Comment: now am trying ...can anybody help me..

Comment: What is your `FilePath`? you mentioned `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FilePath)`...

Comment: string FilePath = (Server.MapPath("~\\ReportPDF\\" + "Employeegenderreport.pdf"));

Comment: in my local its working fine.but after hosting did not generate ..and i want to specify a common  path for all client machine..now am given path to into my project

Comment: I think there might be a different problem to your code, that is not here. Use a `try...catch` statement to see what the error is.